# How to secure sensitive PHP files that process Jquery data?

Tags: php, jquery, security, file

On my website, I have a `search.php` page that makes `$.get` requests to pages like `search_data.php` and `search_user_data.php` etc.

The problem is all of these files are located within my public html folder.

Even though someone could browse to `www.mysite.com/search_user_data.php`, all of the data processed is properly escaped and handled, but on a professional level this is inadequate to even have this file within public reach.

I have tried moving the sensitive files to my web root, however since Jquery is making `$.get` requests and passing variables in the URL, this doesn't work.

Does anyone know any methods to firmly secure these vulnerable pages?

Comment: @zerkms So all files on every web page that exists should have no privacy whatsoever?

Comment: PHP is not exposed to the public, hence "server side language". It's executed, and the results are outputted.

Comment: @andrewjackson Right, but I would prefer to not give anyone the chance to be able to play around with the url by doing things like `search_data.php?id=394&pass=493202`. Is that not reasonable?

Comment: Uhm, could any moderator explain why my comment has been deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is normal.

You have PHP files that are reachable in your www directory so apache (or your favored webserver) can read and process them.
If you move them out you can't reach them anymore so there is no real option of that sort.

After all your PHP files for AJAX are just regular php files, likely your other project also contains php files. Right ? They are not more or less at risk than any script on your server.

Make sure you program "clean". Think about evil requests when writing your php functions, not after writing them.
As you already did: correctly quote all incoming input that might hit a database or sensitive function.

You can add security checks on your incoming values and create an automated email if you detect someone trying evil stuff. So you'll likely receive a warning in such cases.
But on the downside: You'll regularly receive warnings because some companies automatically scan websites for possible bugs. So you will receive a warning on such scans as well.

On top of writing your code as "secure" as you can, you may want to add a referer check in your code. That means your PHP file will only react if your website was given as referer when accessing it. That's enough to block 80% of the kids out there.
But on the downside: a few internet users do not send a referer at all, some proxies filter that. (I personally would ignore them, half the (www) internet breaks on them anyway)

One more layer of protection can be added by htaccess, you can do most within PHP but it might still be of interest for you: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I should maybe add: When I make ajax requests and the users have an account on my server then I usually pass a userid and a md5hash of the password (and some salt). That was you can easily see if the ajax request originates from a legal user.

Answer (score 2):

You can store a uid each time your page is loaded and store it in $_SESSION['uid']. You give this uid to javascript by doing :

```
var uid = <?php print $_SESSION['uid']; ?>;
```

Then you pass it with your get request, compare it to your $_SESSION :

```
if($_GET['uid'] != $_SESSION['uid']) // Stop with an error message or send a forbidden header.
```

If it's ok, do what you need.

It's not perfect since someone can request search.php and get the current uid, and then request the other pages, but it may be the best possible solution.

Comment: If you used this method but with `$_POST` instead, would that be alot safer?

Comment: Not really. It would be harder for newbies but quite as simple for others.